# Html tags ul li not working in "windows outlook"?

Tags: html, css, outlook

I am trying to send HTML code as email, when I am using `ul li` in HTML it is not showing unordered list in windows outlook.

```html
 <div>
         <p>Ul Examples For Outlook</p>
         <ul>
             <li>Type 1</li>
             <li>Type 2</li>
             <li>Type 3</li>
             <li>Type 4</li>
         </ul>
    </div>
```

I am expecting email should contain unordered list with bullets.But it does not showing bullet in actual email.Also it adds some margin to ul.

Comment: Hi Pratik. Did you read about HTML rendering in outlook? (there is tons of info about it) In any case, if I set up my outlook to not render HTML, there is nothing you can do against it. Cause those are my settings and I hope even outlook will never allow anyone from outside to change it.

Comment: @caramba This is not case.Apart from ul li ,all other elements are working properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because outlook set some negative margin to lists(I think) so you should set some extra margin to them:

```
 <!– [if gte mso 9]>
 <style>
     li {text-align:-webkit-match-parent; display:list-item;text-indent: -1em;}
     ul, ol{    margin-left: 40px !important;}
 </style>
 <![endif]–>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `<ul>` and `<li>` with the proprietary CSS property mso-special-format:bullet;
Here's a code example :

```
<ul>
   <li style="mso-special-format:bullet;">Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried list-style:disc / list-style-type: disc; it didn't work.

Comment: Ok, than the best way to do bulleted lists in email is to mimic them with tables. Ex.: http://jsfiddle.net/GHC7m/2/

Comment: Actually data is dynamic,So Convert it to tables then it works

Answer (score 2):

If other HTML is getting rendered correctly, then my guess would be Outlook changing default CSS initial values, even though that would be surprising.

Maybe try adding this to your CSS ?

```
ul {
  list-style: circle;
}
```

Comment: I tried list-style:disc / list-style-type: disc; it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook is designed to support only a sub-set of HTML 4, so some HTML tags are simply ignored.

One way to do it is below.

Select more commands to customize your quick access toolbar in Outlook

2. Choose the "attach" function and "add" it to the toolbar
3. Open the "attach a file" window from the quick access toolbar
4. Select the HTML file you need to import BUT do not click to INSERT yet
5. Switch the "insert" button with the "insert as a text" button and click

Here's the magic! The HTML file will be imported and visualized properly in your email. At this point you'll just need to send it to your audience.

I hope this short guide will speed you up when working with HTML emails in Outlook 365.

Thanks to Maurizio for the guide

Answer (score 0):

Outlook will often drop the bullet outside the margins, or I have issues with mobile clients seeing different margins that Outlook clients.

So here is what I use to create bulleted lists in html for delivery to MS Outlook clients.

I use a CSS tag to push the left margin to the right a bit (20px, in this example), then use "text-indent" to pull the first line back (-15px, in this example)

I also use the numeric character reference ID for the bullet (`&#8226;`)

```
p.bullet {
    margin: 10px 0px 20px 20px;
    text-indent: -15px;
}

<p class="bullet">&#8226;&ensp;List item 1.</p>
<p class="bullet">&#8226;&ensp;List item 2.</p>
```

I have had no issues with it rendering correctly in MS Outlook, or other mobile email apps.